# USB ports "crash" randomly and often on 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, bluetooth, thunderbolt, usb-c

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 but this was also an issue on any version dating back to 2018 (including 18.04).

I have a Dell XPS 13 (2018) that has three USB-C ports. Two of them are on the left side and are labeled "Thunderbolt". Whenever I have devices (mouse, keyboard, monitor/hub), the two "thunderbolt" ports will randomly freeze and I have to unplug/replug devices for them to come back on. This happens pretty often and is extremely annoying. I've also noticed that it will sometimes even interrupt my bluetooth audio or even the headphone jack audio. The single USB-C port on the right side of the laptop seems to be unaffected by all of this.

The one thing that doesn't go out is my monitor connected to those plugs. If I have a monitor, keyboard, and monitor all connected to the same hub that's plugged into one of those two thunderbolt ports, the keyboard and mouse will freeze but the display will stay on unaffected.

This has happened with multiple different devices and hubs that all work fine on other machines, so I know the issue is not with the devices themselves.

What could be causing this?

dmesg after USB "crash":

```
[442620.376698] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[442620.376717] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 06-38] add_size 1000
[442620.376718] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
[442620.376720] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[442620.376722] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3a-6d] add_size 1000
[442620.376723] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-6d] add_size 4000
[442620.376727] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[442620.376728] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[442620.376729] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[442620.376729] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[442620.376734] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442620.376735] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442620.376736] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376737] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376737] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376738] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376739] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376740] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376742] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376743] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376744] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442620.376745] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442620.376746] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376747] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376748] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442620.376749] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508545] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[442625.508565] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 06-38] add_size 1000
[442625.508568] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
[442625.508570] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[442625.508572] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3a-6d] add_size 1000
[442625.508574] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-6d] add_size 4000
[442625.508577] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[442625.508579] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[442625.508580] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[442625.508581] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[442625.508586] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442625.508587] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442625.508588] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508589] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508590] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508591] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508592] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508593] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508594] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508595] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508597] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442625.508598] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442625.508599] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508600] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508601] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442625.508602] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442633.480320] r8152 4-2.4:1.0 enx000108b002e8: Tx timeout
[442638.600400] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[442638.600411] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[442638.600454] r8152 4-2.4:1.0 enx000108b002e8: Tx status -108
[442638.600460] r8152 4-2.4:1.0 enx000108b002e8: Tx status -108
[442638.600464] r8152 4-2.4:1.0 enx000108b002e8: Tx status -108
[442638.600468] r8152 4-2.4:1.0 enx000108b002e8: Tx status -108
[442638.600519] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[442638.600574] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[442638.600579] usb 3-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 14
[442638.600620] usb 3-2.4.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[442638.601354] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[442638.601360] usb 4-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[442638.603245] usb 3-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 15
[442638.641817] r8152 4-2.4:1.0 enx000108b002e8: Using pass-thru MAC addr 10:65:30:b9:9c:ab
[442638.720850] usb 3-2.4.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
[442638.761090] usb 3-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[442638.939965] usb 3-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
[442638.942303] usb 3-2.5: USB disconnect, device number 8
[442651.284777] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 1
[442651.284781] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[442651.284974] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[442651.284980] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 1
[442651.284982] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[442651.285109] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[442651.285111] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[442651.285214] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[442651.320704] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[442651.320719] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 06-38] add_size 1000
[442651.320720] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
[442651.320722] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[442651.320723] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3a-6d] add_size 1000
[442651.320725] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-6d] add_size 4000
[442651.320728] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[442651.320729] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[442651.320730] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[442651.320731] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[442651.320734] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442651.320735] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442651.320736] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320737] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320738] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320738] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320739] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320740] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320741] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320742] pcieport 0000:04:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320744] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442651.320745] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[442651.320745] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320746] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320747] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[442651.320748] pcieport 0000:04:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[442656.294645] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[442656.297221] pci_bus 0000:05: busn_res: [bus 05] is released
[442656.298859] pci_bus 0000:06: busn_res: [bus 06-38] is released
[442656.299481] pci_bus 0000:39: busn_res: [bus 39] is released
[442656.301787] pci_bus 0000:3a: busn_res: [bus 3a-6d] is released
[442656.301865] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04-6d] is released
```

This section from dmesg might be particularly useful:

```
[442638.600519] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[442638.600574] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[442638.600579] usb 3-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 14
[442638.600620] usb 3-2.4.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[442638.601354] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[442638.601360] usb 4-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[442638.603245] usb 3-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 15
[442638.641817] r8152 4-2.4:1.0 enx000108b002e8: Using pass-thru MAC addr 10:65:30:b9:9c:ab
[442638.720850] usb 3-2.4.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
[442638.761090] usb 3-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[442638.939965] usb 3-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
[442638.942303] usb 3-2.5: USB disconnect, device number 8
[442651.284777] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 1
[442651.284781] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[442651.284974] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[442651.284980] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 1
[442651.284982] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[442651.285109] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[442651.285111] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
```

Comment: how many devices are you trying to use at the same time?  Is it possible that you are exceeding the bandwidth of the USB controller?  It seems this could be the case especially if one of the USB devices is a monitor -- A monitor will consume a LOT more bandwidth than a keyboard, mouse, or other common USB peripherals.

Comment: Just three: monitor, mouse, and keyboard. It makes sense that a display would take up a lot of bandwidth, but given how common USB docks with display support are, I'd think it wouldn't be an issue? At least when using even fewer devices than the actual HUB has ports for.

Comment: maybe the *hub* that you are using doesn't support the bandwidth?

Comment: Maybe? But I've had the same issue with a different hub using a lower res monitor.